# Best method to create HD graphics for android games

Tags: java, android, eclipse, graphics, tablet

Is there a good method to create HD like graphics for regular 480x800 devices as well as tablets? So far I can create HD like graphics for only 480x800 devices. And since i'm using OpenGL i place all of my graphics in the assets folder. My images are in the 480x800 format. I have thought of multiple ways and they are listed below.

1. I tried using 480x800 graphics and using OpenGL to stretch it to a tablet with GL_LINEAR. As expected, the graphics were great on the 480x800 devices and average if not poor on the tablet.
2. I have not tried this but I believe this to be a good method (need clarification). Using seamless textures and creating my background from those. (problem with this is that my character would become non-HD like).
3. (Soon to be tried) Using the res folder instead of the assets folder. Seperating tablet graphics and phone graphics. However, i have not come up with a good method to place these graphics in identical places with OpenGL. [need clarification on this :)]

What are some of your good methods to create HD games for both 480x800, 480x854 and tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the one you probably expected - for the best results you should create images of different sizes and use the most appropriate set.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'll be using a mix of 2 and 3. Also, Grim would you mind taking a look at my other topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365538/what-are-the-capabilities-of-canvas-vs-opengl

Comment: That's beyond me mate, sorry.